# Execute lambda expression immediately after its definition?

Tags: c#, lambda

Is there a way to execute a lambda expression immediately after its definition?

In other words (Invalid C# code):

```csharp
(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); }).Invoke();
```

Comment: Wait... what? Why is it a lambda expression?

Comment: The reason your code is invalid is because you haven't told the compiler whether you want an `Action` or an `Expression<Action>`.  If you cast that lambda expression to `Action`, you'll be able to call `Invoke` on it or use the method-call syntax `()` to invoke it.

Comment: My imagination might be failing me, is there an actual need to do this?

Comment: Got it. It makes sense now. @Tejs made it very clear with his answer.

Comment: This is a more functional form of code, it clearly defines which part of the current method that is used solely to one task. Not necessarily more efficient, but I have used it to isolate code without needing to break it out to a new function with all the scoping problems that means.

Comment: It is also helpful instead of a switch expression if you can't use C# 8, because you can avoid duplicating the left-hand side of the assignment and the `break` statement in every switch case.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Sure.

```
new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); })();
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 22):

Another "option", which is just the other two answers in a slightly different guise:

```
((Action)(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); }))();
```

The reason, *as directly taken from phoog's comment*:

> ...you haven't told the compiler whether you want an `Action` or an `Expression<Action>`. If you *cast* that lambda expression to `Action`, you'll be able to call Invoke on it or use the method-call syntax () to invoke it.

It sure gets ugly though, and I do not know of a place where this form is ever useful, as it cannot be used for recursion without a name...

Comment: You totally can do recursion with this, using the Y combinator : `public delegate T Recursive<T>(Recursive<T> f, T n); static void Main(string[] args) { System.Console.WriteLine("Factorial 5 = {0}", new Recursive<int>((f, n) => f(f, n))(new Recursive<int>((f, n) => (n == 0) ? 1 : n * f(f, n - 1)), 5)); }`. It's a hack from the purely functional world, which basically declares a function `f` taking itself as a parameter, and recursively calling itself by passing `f`. To start the recursion, this function is passed to another which calls `f` with `f` and the initial value of the parameter.

Comment: I found this useful for the purposes of performing an await from a non async function: ((Action)(async () => { x = await task; }))();   I was able to declare the lambda async and call it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this:

```
Action runMe = () => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); };
runMe();
```

Comment: Correct. The compiler will interpret the lambda syntax as shorthand for a delegate. It's only if you're assigning into an `Expression<Delegate>` type that it will construct the expression tree.

Comment: This won't compile because the compiler can't figure out whether you want an `Action` or an `Expression<Action>`.

Comment: @phoog is correct. This will not compile. "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable."

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how this might be used. You want to initialize a constructor with the result of a few lines of code that can't be written as a function because that is how the 3rd party API is structured.

It is just glue code to prevent writing a  standalone function that is never called anywhere else. I'm using `Func` instead of `Action`, but the answer is the same as user166390.

```
        // imagine several dozens of lines that look like this
        // where the result is the return value of a function call
        fields.Add(new ProbeField(){ 
            Command = "A",
            Field = "Average",
            Value = be.GetAverage()
        });

        // now you need something that can't be expressed as function call
        // so you wrap it in a lambda and immediately call it.
        fields.Add(new ProbeField(){ 
            Command = "C",
            Field = "Cal Coeff",
            Value = ((Func<string>)(() => {
                CalCoef coef;
                Param param;
                be.GetCalibrationCoefficients(out coef, out param);
                return coef.lowDet1.ToString();
            }))()
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

For my own projects I've sometimes written a tiny reusable helper function to make the syntax for an immediately invoked lambda look shorter. This 'Inv' was inspired by the similar 'fun' function in the LanguageExt library.

```
// Helper utility functions
public static void Inv(Action a) => a();
public static T Inv<T>(Func<T> f) => f();

private static void TestMethod()
{
    // Action example
    Inv(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"));
    // Func example with no parameters
    bool result = Inv(() =>
    {
        if (1 == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });
}
```

You could also extend this with a few other overloads to make it so you could pass in parameters, but these look a bit more cumbersome syntax wise and may not be as helpful.

```
public static Func<A, T> Inv<A, T>(Func<A, T> f) => f;
public static Func<A, B, T> Inv<A, B, T>(Func<A, B, T> f) => f;

string printNumber = Inv((int number) => $"This is the number {number}")(5);
int addedNumbers = Inv((int x, int y) => x + y)(5, 6);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

Task.Run(()=>{
     //do something
});
```

programmers really like to make things more difficult than they should be

You can add a 500ms delay with

```
Task.Run(()=>{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    //do something
});
```

and then the next logical extension is passing parameters to your anonymous function. You can do this with scope:

```
var x=1;
Task.Run(()=>{
    x++;
});
```

and then you can basically throw the rest of C# out the window. If you like this functional style, I suggest JS or C.