# Is there a C# equivalent to this javascript-esqe code? (Immediately calling a lambda)

Tags: c#, lambda

I was wondering if there is any way of writing the equivalent of this:

```
string test = () => { return "text"; }(); // Error
```

Notice the () at the end, which would have the effect of immediately evaluating and setting the return value to 'test'.

As far as I know there is no way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `string test = new Func<string>(() => "text")();`

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198370/execute-lambda-expression-immediately-after-its-definition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify the delegate type:

```
string test = (new Func<string>(() => { return "text"; }))();
```

or just

```
string test = (new Func<string>(() => "text"))();
```

if you're doing this to reduce the scope of some variables local to the lambda you can declare nested scopes within methods in C# e.g.

```
string test;
{
    var r = new Random();
    string i = r.Next().ToString();
    test = i + i;
}
```